# Error while installing Pycharm: "Prefs file removed from backround"

Tags: python, java, pycharm

In the process of installing `pycharm`, in the final step, when I run `./pycharm.sh` I get the following:

> WARNING: Prefs file removed in background/home/daniel/.java/.userPrefs/prefs.xml

And then it just stays that way forever.

Would anyone please help me fix it?

Comment: Did you workaround this issue? If so, how? If not, could you please give more details on the installation steps you followed, your Ubuntu version, whether you had already installed it before or not, etc. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

To try to solve this issue you may use the `wmname` from https://tools.suckless.org/x/wmname to make the JVM believe you are running a different window manager:

```
wmname LG3D
```

It's needed to restart the application after running this command.